# What is stopping Google and Ubuntu - two opensource icons from seamless login?

Tags: login, android, google

Lack of a desktop OS & apps is the only thing that stops many from using Google account, Google Docs and Google for Business. 
Integration with a popular online account service is the only thin that is missing for Ubuntu to become one of truly leading OS. 
I'm not asking "Why doing this". I'm asking **what is actually missing to link my Android device and Ubuntu desktop?**

Cross reference: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/KbZ6yvUObfc;context-place=forum/gmail

Clarification (as straight as possible):
Chrome OS is not common, Libre Office is not common, Windows + Office is hell but without any good competitor.
Correct me if I'm wrong, but
* Ubuntu + Google apps for Business + Nexus >= Windows + Office + Windows Phone

Comment: Ubuntu is going to link to Ubuntu phones. Seems more logical then to hand over your system to google.

Comment: But that does not make sense. How many guys out there are using these devices with just a year-old mobile platform?

Comment: Let's even look wider. The business clients make the major part of success. How many companies have left Linus and Google and opted to Windows and Office for Business just because they have all platforms seamless: web, mobile and most important - desktop?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "to link". You can plug in the USB and manipulate all the accessible files on your Android device... What else are you exactly thinking of?

Answer (score 2):

I think your question is why can't you set your ubuntu computer up so you log in, add software, and control settings via a Google account. I suppose a summary of why there hasn't been a move so you can entirely control your ubuntu computer from a google account is (in my opinion):

1. Google does not write Ubunutu, or Unity, or Debian (the upstream version), or even very much of the linux kernel. For them to have the account control tools, or install tools server side would be a lot of work for them, and an uphill battle to keep it up to date.
2. Ubuntu is owned by a different company: Canonical. Even if they wanted could based centralised settings for the desktop, why would the have it set up to run with google rather than their own cloud?
3. We already have centralised software repositories and apt-get to allow us to keep software up to date. But without all the malware on that is on the android store. And without every program being able to demand ridiculous permissions to look at your data and talk home just to turn your LED into a flash light.
4. Finally, Ubuntu has its community, who I assume for the most part, like me, do not want to hand the keys to their computers over to google. We are happy to use cloud services for specific tasks as an when we want. Perhaps even back up all our system settings to the cloud. But google snooping/control fully integrated into my computer no thanks.

I think the opposite question is on many of our minds. When will there be a viable phone operating system which is all open source, has a sensible permission system, gives me root control, and is supported by vendors rather than hacked on voiding warranty?

Comment: But let's just assume it's all possible: same as `windows+office+windows_phone=daily_use&business`, there would be `ubuntu+google+nexus=daily_use&business`. With the initial integration there would be a clear continuation in google desktop apps (real, not the chrome-based) and this would finally make a serious competitor for MS.

Comment: The big hurdle is vendor support not login. People use Windows because the computer comes with Windows. Most people don't like to even use a recovery disk let alone pick a new operating system. In fact many people don't really understand what an operating system is. Until you can walk into a high street shop and buy a linux machine it will never hit the mainstream.
I agree a good cloud and desktop office app would be useful/essential for many, but I doubt google want to make Docs into a desktop app, but it seems there is a push for cloud based libre office. We will have to wait and see.

Comment: Yes, that's the issues to face. So I still think there is a point to face them.  - Ubuntu is a lot more common than Chrome OS (though Chrome has it's vendors)  - Google Docs is a lot more common than Libre Office.  If we forget the drawbacks for a minute, would you as a tech director of an enterprise company choose Windows+Office or let's say "Ubuntu for Business"?